# UIAlertView clickedButtonAtIndex with presentModalViewController

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uialertview

I am trying to call a view via presentModalViewController from a UIAlertView button. The code is below, the NSlog is displayed in the console so I know that code execution is indeed reaching that point. Also, there are no errors or anything displayed:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex])
{
    NSLog(@" The username is: %@ AND the password is: %@ ",textField.text,passTextField.text);

 // do some logic in here later 

    CompanyViewController *companyViewController = [[[CompanyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CompanyViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];  
    [self presentModalViewController:companyViewController animated:YES];
}
[textField resignFirstResponder];
[passTextField resignFirstResponder];

}
```

***** Edit: The method above belongs to a UIViewController. Below is the interface file:

```
@interface testingViewController : UIViewController  <UITextFieldDelegate>
{
UITextField *textField;
UITextField *passTextField;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *textField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *passTextField;
@property (readonly) NSString *enteredText;
@property (readonly) NSString *enteredPassword;

@end
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this method belong to a View or ViewController?

Comment: Is your nib named CompanyViewController.nib or CompanyView.nib? (I've made this mistake a few times myself with `initWithNibName`).

Comment: Hi. I just doubled checked my project - the nib is CompanyViewController.nib. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you are trying to call presentModalViewController from something that is not a viewController? For example a View.

Comment: Hi, I just edited my question - thanks. 
The method belongs to a viewController.

Answer (score 0):

Just try using something different with Navigation Controller:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

  if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex])
  {

      CompanyViewController *companyViewController = [[CompanyViewController alloc] init];
      UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:companyViewController];

      [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
      [navController release];
  }

}
```

Hope that will work..